# OpenVpn Wifi cant connect but connects with ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, vpn, openvpn

I have recently installed my ubuntu 18.04 OS on my laptop(lenovo). At work we have an openvpn configuration to connect when we are at home and while everything is OK in Windows in Ubuntu I have problems to connect using WIFI. I have tried connecting using ethernet and it works. I have downloaded and installed network-manager-openvpn-gnome . Can you please guide me?

Comment: Do you have firewall installed? It may interfere with vpn work.

Comment: @JoKeR I have fixes the issue. I had wrong hosts file configuration